# Ubuntu 15.10 does not recognize Gamdias Hermes keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard

[This](https://gamdiasgaming.com/product/hermes-ultimate-brown-mechanical-keyboard/) is a great mechanical keyboard. Well laid out, well constructed, works well in windows. All the settings are stored in the keyboard so you dont need the software running to use it. But it does not work in linux. AT ALL. Completely unresponsive.

Bus 008 Device 005: ID 1b80:b400 Afatech

Bus 008 Device 004: ID 1af3:0001

Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1b80:b402 Afatech

Is there any way to edit the config file in ubuntu to get it to recognize this peripheral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my Gamdias Hermes Keyboard to work on my Linux desktop which is using Ubuntu Mate but I believe it will work will all forms of Linux distributions. I Want to make an application to run at startup to get it to work but I am personally unable to make it.
But the fix I was able to find is.

```
Sudo cat /dev/usb/hiddev#
```

You also need to press some keys on the keyboard to make sure it is the keyboard but if it is it will

This will require you to use a separate keyboard or mouse and a few tries to figure out the number of the keyboard but in all it has worked for me every time I find the right file.

*You will need to do this command at every boot*

Good Luck

Comment: Does just running the `sudo cat /dev/hiddev#` command make the keyboard work, or are there additional steps you forgot to include?

Comment: I forgot to add /usb/ to the command sorry. But yes as far as I have been able to figure out it just works including the macros but those have to be set using windows first before they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the v78 firmware on Gamdias FTP Server at ftp://ftp.gamdias.com/gamdias/HERA_extension/keyboard/HERMES/GKB2000_2010_Linux/ . Unpack the FWUpdate-75&78.zip, run HermesUPDATE and select HERMES_ap_2014_04_18_78.hex file. This will upgrade the firmware to v78 which  works with Linux. This keyboard is great, I use it on Arch Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). Then consider improving your answers formating.